# How can I correct the terminal size of a `docker exec psql`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker exec -tiu postgres some_db_container psql db_name`

This is such a convenient command to connect to any docker container one has access to, without having to discover the username and password used by the app to connect.

Trouble is, the TTY allocated at this point is insane. It doesn't know how big the terminal is, it doesn't make a line break when it tries to wrap the line, and it goes completely off the rails if you try to edit the line in the middle. Most of the time it is easier to write your query in a text editor and paste it in.

I thought maybe it's because no TTY was allocated when the container was made, but `tty: true` in the docker-compose didn't seem to have an effect.

I'm surprised I can't find even a discussion of this problem on the internet because the only other way of connecting to it  is to know the IP of the container and the credentials for a user to connect with.

Is there some fix for this? I'd rather not have to dig out production passwords every time I want to investigate an issue, when I could connect as the postgres user if I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and after some researching found this answer https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794#issuecomment-312873988.

The trick is to tell the terminal in the container its size.

```
docker exec -tiu -e COLUMNS="`tput cols`" -e LINES="`tput lines`" postgres some_db_container psql db_name
```

This solves the issue for me.

Comment: I've also discovered that I can just resize the terminal after connection. F11 does this for my terminal emulator, so I can just press that twice. This doesn't help if you're in the console but that's very rare these days.

Comment: `docker exec -it -e COLUMNS=200 8855160e50fc ps aux` for those of you trying to use ps aux to see what microservice is running :)